"-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('" error while trying to activate project using Conda
I am trying to create a project using Conda.
conda create --name cooking-assistant python=3.11

The project is created but when I try to activate it, it gives me the above-mentioned error. Also, I cannot find any project-related file in the directory, where I am creating this project.

How exactly are you activating the project?

where is the """it gives me the above-mentioned error. """ ?
